# Netbeans не видит отдельные классы CSS

Tags: css, netbeans

В программе имеется файл css в котором описаны классы, но по факту Netbeans пишет что они отсутствуют, причем только 4. Остальные классы работают отлично. Перепроверил и путь к файлу и описание классов в css и коде. Ниже прикреплены следующие файлы:

1. Header страницы приложения.
2. Код страницы поиска и вывода согласно специализации работника.( не видит классы css( employee_list,employee_info,employee_details.)
3. файл css.

```html
<!-- Постоянные элементы такие как шапка с поиском и логгером страницы, левое меню,алфавитный поиск вынесены отдельно-->
<!--Данная страница отвечает за шапку приложения-->

<!--Подключение необходимых библиотек, пакетов, содержащих классы-->
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@page import="by.testcracker.beans.Profession"%>
<%@page import="by.testcracker.beans.ProfessionList"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Hot Junior::Search</title>
        <link href="../css/style_search.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    </head>
    
    <body>
        
        <!--Блок поиска атрибуда поисковой строки.Проверка был ли заполнен,иначе достаем из атриббута сесиии.-->
        <%
            request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
            String searchString = "";
            
            
            if (request.getParameter("search_string") != null) {
                searchString = request.getParameter("search_string");
                session.setAttribute("search_string", searchString);
            } else if (session.getAttribute("search_string") != null) {
                searchString = session.getAttribute("search_string").toString();
            } else {
                session.setAttribute("search_string", searchString);
            }
            
            if (request.getParameter("username") != null) {
                session.setAttribute("username", request.getParameter("username"));
            }          
        %>
        <!--Конец блока поиска атрибута поисковой строки-->
        
        <div class="container">

            <div class="header">
                <div class="logo">
                    <a href="search.jsp"><img src="../images/logo.png" alt="Логотип" name="logo" /></a>

                </div>
                <div class="descr">
                    <h3>Онлайн-база молодых соискателей <br/> Найди способного Junior'a!</h3>

                </div>
                
                <!--блок отображения юзернейма в соответствиии с хранящимся атрибутом-->
                <div class="welcome">
                    <h3>Добро пожаловать, <%=session.getAttribute("username")%> !</h3>
                    <h6><a href="../index.jsp">Выход</a></h6>
                <!--конец блока отображения юзернейма-->
                
                <!--форма с поиском и кнопкой-->
                </div>
                            <div class="search_form">
                                <form name="search_form" method="GET" action="specialization.jsp">
                                    <input type="text" name="search_string" value="<%=searchString%>" size="110"/>
                                    <input class="search_button" type="submit" value="Поиск"/>
                                   
                                </form>
                            </div>
                <!--форма с поиском и кнопкой-->     
                
            </div>
```

```html
<!--Cтраница отображения данных согласно специализации-->

<!--Подключаем нужные бины и библиотеки-->
<%@page import="by.testcracker.beans.EmployeeList"%>
<%@page import="java.util.ArrayList"%>
<%@page import="by.testcracker.beans.Employee"%>

<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<%@include file="../WEB-INF/jspf/left_menu.jspf" %>

<jsp:useBean id="employeeList" class="by.testcracker.beans.EmployeeList" scope="page"/>

<%@include file="../WEB-INF/jspf/letters.jspf" %>


<div class="employee_list">

    <!--Блок проверки типа поиска с заполнением текущего списка работников согласно критерия поиска-->
    <%
        ArrayList<Employee> list = null;
      
        if (request.getParameter("profession_id") != null) {
            long professionId = Long.valueOf(request.getParameter("profession_id"));
            list = employeeList.getEmployeesBySpecialization(professionId);
        } else if (request.getParameter("letter") != null) {
            String letter = request.getParameter("letter");
            list = employeeList.getEmployeeByLetter(letter);
        } else if (request.getParameter("search_string") != null) {
            String searchStr = request.getParameter("search_string");
            

            if (searchStr != null && !searchStr.trim().equals("")) {
                list = employeeList.getEmployeeBySearch(searchStr);
            }
        }
       %>
     <!--Конец проверки и заполнения-->
     
     <!--Выводим количество соискателей согласно критерию поиска-->
    <h5 style="text-align: left; margin-top:20px;">Найдено соискателей: <%=list.size() %> </h5>
              
    
    
    <!--Передаем в атрибут сессии текущий список работников и выводим его пользователю-->
    <%  
                session.setAttribute("currentBookList", list);
                for (Employee employee : list) {

    %>

    <div class="employee_info">
        <div >
            <p> <%=employee.getName()%></p>
        </div>
        
        <div class="employee_details">
            
            
            <br><strong>№:</strong> <%=employee.getID()%>
            <br><strong>ФИО:</strong> <%=employee.getName()%>
            <br><strong>КОД профессии:</strong> <%=employee.getProfessionID()%>
            <br><strong>ТЕЛ:</strong> <%=employee.getTel()%> 
            <form name="Edit" action="../Edit.jsp?employee_id=<%=employee.getID()%>" method="POST">
                <input type="submit" style="width:150px"  value="Редактировать данные" />
            </form>
            <form name="Del" action="../delete.jsp?employee_id=<%=employee.getID()%>" method="POST">
                <input type="submit" style="width:150px"  value="Удалить соискателя" />
            </form>
           
                
                
            
        </div>
    </div>


    <%}%>
    <!-- конец блока вывода-->
    

</div>
```

```css
ul.nav a, ul.nav a:visited { 
 padding: 5px 5px 5px 15px;
 display: block; 
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #000;
}
body {
 font: 100%/1.4 Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 background-color: #EEE;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 color: #000;
}

ul, ol, dl { 
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
}
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p {
 margin-top: 0;  
 padding-right: 15px;
 padding-left: 15px; 
}

a img { 
 border: none;
}


a:link {
 color:#414958;
 text-decoration: underline; 
}
a:visited {
 color: #4E5869;
 text-decoration: underline;
}
a:hover, a:active, a:focus { 
 text-decoration: none;
}

.container {
 width: 1000px;
 background-color: #FFF;
 margin: 0 auto; 
 height:1800px;
}


.header {
 background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

.sidebar1 {
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    margin: 10px;
}
.content {
    padding: 10px 0;
    width: 65%;
    float: left;
}


ul.nav {
 list-style: none; 
 
 margin-bottom: 15px; 
}
ul.nav li {
 
}
ul.nav a:hover, ul.nav a:active, ul.nav a:focus {
 background-color: #FFFFFF;
 color: #999;
}



.search_form{
    margin:2%;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: #dbe4f6;
    height: 35px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding: 5px;
    float: left;
}

.welcome{
    text-align: right;
    padding-top: 50px;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 8pt;
   
    
}



.logo{
    text-align: left;
    padding: 20px;
    float:left;
    width:100px;
    height: 100px;
}

.descr{
    float: left;
    width: 600px;
    text-align: left;
    padding-top: 50px;
}


.employee_list {
    float:left;
    width: 750px;

}


.employee_list h3{
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.employee_title p{
    color:#378de5 ;
    font-weight: bold; 
    font-size: 15px; 
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.employee_title{
    height: 50px;
    float:left;
}

.employee_info{
    width: 210px;
    height: 200px;
    font-size: 12px;
    float:left;
    margin:15px;
}



.employee_details{
    float:left;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.letters{
    float:left;
    height: 20px;
    margin: 10px;
}

.letters a{
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: Думаю нужен более подробный пример.

Comment: Уточнил, надеюсь, будет читаемо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не знаю, проблема ли это в моем коде или в IDE, но вся проблема решилась изменением параметра weight в классе .employee_list. Причем со значения 750 на другое, а затем обратно на 750. Все нарисовалось ровненько после сохранения и так, как нужно. Я в замешательстве :)